# How to create a Outlook 2013 Add-in Command?

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to create a Ribbon Button in the calendar view of Outlook that extracts some properties (e.g. data, time) of the current selected calendar item (appointment) in the Outlook calendar view and that creates a new Email with the properties listed in the text.

I also appreciate answers that will provide links to blogs, articles or videos related to this task, as I couldn't find much with the necessary guidance and explanation I need for this. Also other solutions to do this with Outlook on-board tools are welcome. **Important:** I do not just want to forward the appointment as an attachment to a new Email, I want the properties as text **in** the Email.

Remarks:

1. I have no background in MS Office plugin development, please consider this
2. I have successfully done this walktrough with the VBA code samples  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx), that adds some text to every new Email message, but I couldn't figure out how to go on effectively to get my task done

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VBA doesn't allow creating a ribbon custom UI for Outlook. You need to develop a COM add-in for Outlook if you want to create a custom UI. Read more about that in the [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

VSTO provides two main ways for creating a custom ribbon UI:

1. [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)
2. [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx)

You may find the Fluent UI described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Also, you may consider creating web-based add-ins (former known as Mail Aps), see [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook) for more information.